# "Where" clause in linq to sql query using DateTime?

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I'm trying to run a query of a table with the columns Domain, LastUsed, and FreqInHours In c#.

I just want to return all the Domains that I need to crawl.I find this out by checking the datetime that they were last Crawled (LastUsed) and how frequently they should be crawled (ex. every 6 hours). If the current date/time - the time it was last crawled is greater than the frequency I add want to return that domain.

Here is the current query I've written:

```
var query = (from c in context.SitemapFreqs
             where (DateTime.Now - c.LastUsed).TotalHours > c.Freq
             select c.domain);
```

Here is the exception I'm being given:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ?
>   ToDateTime(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated  into a store expression.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DbFunctions` class and method `DiffHours`.

Here is an example:

```
var query = (from c in context.SitemapFreqs
             where DbFunctions.DiffHours(DateTime.Now,c.LastUsed) > c.Freq
             select c.domain);
```

Here is the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.diffhours(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.DiffHours(System.Nullable%7BSystem.DateTime%7D,System.Nullable%7BSystem.DateTime%7D)). Hope it helps.

Comment: Switch the DateTime.Now and the c.LastUsed and that's exactly it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you are right @CameronRaymond.  You are always welcome

Answer (score 0):

Complex DateTime stuff is a bit much for Linq2SQL to handle.

If it's a relatively small amount of data, load it all into memory first:

```
var query = (from c in context.SitemapFreqs.ToList()
             where (DateTime.Now - c.LastUsed).TotalHours > c.Freq
             select c.domain);
```

If it's a larger amount of data, you can use DbFunctions, or provide the query yourself.

```
context.SitemapFreqs.SqlQuery("SELECT * from SitemapFreqs WHERE DATEDIFF('hour', GETDATE(), LastUsed) > Freq")
```

If you make sure the query returns the columns the SitemapFreqs object expects, it will map the objects just like it would anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `c.LastUsed` property is nullable. You can subtract nullable DateTimes using the `c.LastUsed.Value` property, but you should know that if it is null, this will throw an exception as you can't subtract a DateTime - `null`. I believe you have two options:

1. Change the property LastUsed in your class to a non-nullable DateTime by removing the ?.
2. Create a method inside of your class that determines if the `DateTime? LastUsed` is equal to null. If it is, return something where your LINQ query will ignore that value. (I.E: Set the value of LastUsed = `DateTime.Now` so that your LINQ query comes back as 0).

Hope this helps.